# ¿por que codova build android crea un debug.apk pero sin actualizar los cambios?

Tags: android, ionic, cordova

realizo los cambios que necesito en mi aplicacion de ionic 4, genero el archivo debugueable con

```
cordova build android
```

lo pruebo en un dispositivo fisico para realizar pruebas hasta ahi todo bien, el problema viene cuando se ejecuta la aplicacion por que muestra todo sin los cambios que realize como si tan solo la hubiese reinstalado, alguien sabe que puede estar saliendo mal, cualquier ayuda es buena, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido Andres, aclarar que el comando para generar el archivo que dices en Ionic 4 es:

```
ionic cordova build android
```

ya que este comando, según la documentación oficial prepara y compila el proyecto

Te dejo este enlace para consultar el tema:

[ionic cordova build](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-build)

---

como recomendación, seria bueno que hagas la prueba con un dispositivo conectado, y luego del

```
ionic cordova build android
```

hagas un

```
ionic cordova run android
```

para verificar que los cambios se hayan hecho de manera correcta.

Comment: excelente, has resuelto mi problema, gracias